# How to map through array with null/empty element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, null

I am trying to map through an array that contains null/empty elements, which outputs the following file:

```json
{
    "data": [
        [null, { "value": "Position1" }, { "value": "Timmy" }],
        [null, { "value": "Position2" }, { "value": "Bobby" }],
        [null, { "value": "Position3" }, { "value": "johnny" }],
        [null, { "value": "Position4" }, { "value": "Jimmy" }]
    ],
    "positionCells": [
        { "row": 0, "column": 2, "position": "Position1" },
        { "row": 1, "column": 2, "position": "Position2" },
        { "row": 2, "column": 2, "position": "Position3" },
        { "row": 3, "column": 2, "position": "Position4" }
    ]
}
```

Instead of writing 'null' for the null element I would like to output something like: {"value": ""}

I tried doing that with the following, but when I do the console.log, it seems like map is skipping the null element. console.log does not show the null object. What am I missing?

```js
let output = {
    data: sheet.map((e) => {
        return e.map((f) => {
            console.log('f: ', f);
            if (f === null || f === undefined) {
                return { value: '' };
            } else {
                return f;
            }
        });
    }),
    positionCells: positionCells,
};
console.log('output: ', output);
```

Comment: I have copied the data and code into my own IDE (running js file through node.js), I could not seem to recreate the error, It worked exactly to your specification. How are you running this?

Comment: Please update your post to show this code even running, because right now `sheet` is not defined and it's definitely not the data you're showing, because that's an object, not an array. Ideally: reduce your code because you can trivially prove to yourself that `null` maps just fine, even something simple like taking that `data` property and then running `data.map(list => list.map(e => e===null))` shows no problems there.

Comment: It might have to do with the array element being empty and not null.

Answer (score 2):

Just have the nested `map` run on the elements and the return the non-null items and null items separately. Have a look at this snippet

```js
const input = {
  data: [
          [null, { value: "Position1" }, { value: "Timmy" }],
          [null, { value: "Position2" }, { value: "Bobby" }],
          [null, { value: "Position3" }, { value: "johnny" }],
          [null, { value: "Position4" }, { value: "Jimmy" }]
    ],
  positionCells: [
         { row: 0, column: 2, position: "Position1" },
         { row: 1, column: 2, position: "Position2" },
         { row: 2, column: 2, position: "Position3" },
         { row: 3, column: 2, position: "Position4" }
  ]
};

const data = input.data.map((value) => {
  const nested = value.map((item) => {
     if (!item) {
       return { value: "" };
     } else {
       return item;
     }
  });
  return nested;
});

const output = { ...input, data };
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for asking this question, I see what you did here.
This might fix your issue here:

```
data: sheet.map(e => e.map(f => f?f:{value: ''))
```

```js
const sheet = [
        [null, { "value": "Position1" }, { "value": "Timmy" }],
        [null, { "value": "Position2" }, { "value": "Bobby" }],
        [null, { "value": "Position3" }, { "value": "johnny" }],
        [null, { "value": "Position4" }, { "value": "Jimmy" }]
    ];
const positionCells = [
        { "row": 0, "column": 2, "position": "Position1" },
        { "row": 1, "column": 2, "position": "Position2" },
        { "row": 2, "column": 2, "position": "Position3" },
        { "row": 3, "column": 2, "position": "Position4" }
    ];

let output = {
    data: sheet.map(e => e.map(f => f? f: { value: '' })),
    positionCells: positionCells,
};

console.log('output: ', output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.... I figured as much and ended up doing a for loop instead of mapping..... I tried searching and there isn't much information about array.map skipping empty elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking this question, I see what you did here. This might fix your issue here:

```
data: sheet.map(e => {
       e.forEach((f, i) => {
         if(f === null || f === undefined) {
           e[i] = {value: ''};
         }
       })
       return e;
      })
```

```js
const sheet = [
        [null, { "value": "Position1" }, { "value": "Timmy" }],
        [null, { "value": "Position2" }, { "value": "Bobby" }],
        [null, { "value": "Position3" }, { "value": "johnny" }],
        [null, { "value": "Position4" }, { "value": "Jimmy" }]
    ];
const positionCells = [
        { "row": 0, "column": 2, "position": "Position1" },
        { "row": 1, "column": 2, "position": "Position2" },
        { "row": 2, "column": 2, "position": "Position3" },
        { "row": 3, "column": 2, "position": "Position4" }
    ];

let output = {
    data: sheet.map(e => {
   e.forEach((f, i) => {
     if(f === null || f === undefined) {
       e[i] = {value: ''};
     }
   })
   return e;
  }),
    positionCells: positionCells,
};

console.log('output: ', output);
```

Comment: You could update multiple ways to solve, in the same answer itself :)

Comment: you're right :D, I will try to edit the first one thanks :)

Comment: Why posting two answers? Could you maybe merge them and remove one of the two?